# My ng-repeat uses bad links

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on a web app using the MEAN stack which is 99% complete except for this persistent error that's been annoying me. I've deployed it to https://find-nightlife.herokuapp.com/#/

My issue is that when you do a search for a location, the web console will always throw these errors:

```
GET https://find-nightlife.herokuapp.com/%7B%7Bplace.rating_img_url%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)
 %7B%7Bplace.image_url%7D%7D:1 GET https://find-nightlife.herokuapp.com/%7B%7Bplace.image_url%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)
```

Link to the full code on github is here https://github.com/JordanBourne/NightLife

The relevant code:

```
<section class = "results">
<div ng-repeat = "place in results track by $index | limitTo: 10" class = "resultContainer">
    <div class = "resultsList">
        <div class = "placeImg"><img src = "{{place.image_url}}" alt = "{{place.name}}"/></div>
        <div class = "placeAbout">
            <div class = "placeName">
                <a href = "{{place.url}}">{{place.name}}</a> <img src = "{{place.rating_img_url}}" /></div>
            <div class = "placeSnippet">{{place.snippet_text}}</div>
        </div>
        <div class = "areyouGoing"><span style = "color: red">{{error}}</span> {{place.going}} Going 
            <button class = "placeGo notGo" ng-click = "plusOne(place, $index)" ng-show = "attend($index)">Not Going</button>
            <button class = "placeGo letsGo" ng-click = "plusOne(place, $index)" ng-hide = "attend($index)">Let's Go!</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "divider" ng-hide="$last"></div>
</div>
```

```
app.controller('NightLifeCtrl', [
'$scope',
'yelp',
'auth',
function ($scope, yelp, auth) {
    if(yelp.places.data) {
        var attendanceIndex = [];

        yelp.bars.forEach(function(bar) {
            if (bar.people.indexOf(auth.currentUser()) < 0) {
               attendanceIndex.push(0);
            } else {
               attendanceIndex.push(1);
            }
        })

        $scope.attend = function (num) {
            if (attendanceIndex[num] == 1) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        $scope.results = yelp.bars;

        $scope.plusOne = function(place, num) {
            if (!auth.isLoggedIn()) {
                $scope.error = 'You must be logged in!';
                return;
            }

            yelp.addOne(place);

            if (attendanceIndex[num] == 1) {
                return attendanceIndex[num] -= 1;
            } else {
                return attendanceIndex[num] += 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
]);
```

All the angular.js is in public/js/scripts.js, the guilty ng-repeat is in public/nightlife.html, homepage in views/index.ejs

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `<img src = "{{ ..}}">` with `<img ng-src = "{{ ..}}">`. ng-src attribute supports dynamic content.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that! Works just fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Always use the `ng-href=""` attribute when having `{{<expressions>}}` within your href attributes.

This will stop most of the unwanted behaviour.

Here's the [documentation for ng-href.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref)

Quote from the documentation:

> The wrong way to write it:
>
> ```
> <a href="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{hash}}">link1</a>
> ```
>
> The correct way to write it:
>
> ```
> <a ng-href="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{hash}}">link1</a>
> ```